# CASE statement using DYNAMIC sql inside stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I am trying to build a CASE WHEN statement by storing Dynamic SQL in a variable inside a stored proc but I am getting the below error. Could someone share your thoughts on how to resolve this error. Thank you.

**--Code**

```
SELECT
             CASE WHEN  ResultTableName LIKE '%Loss_ByEvent]'
                  THEN  @SQLStmt =
                        N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + ResultTableName + N' (
                        ' + CreateStmt + N'
                        ) ON Loss_ByAnalysis(SliceID)'                    
                  WHEN  ResultTableName LIKE '%Loss_ByGeo]'
                  THEN  @SQLStmt =
                        N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + ResultTableName + N' (
                        ' + CreateStmt + N'
                        ) ON Loss_ByAnalysis(SliceID)'                    
                  ELSE 
                  @SQLStmt =
                        N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + ResultTableName + N' (
                        ' + CreateStmt + N'
                        )'
              END
            ,@DBName = DBName
            ,@ResultTableName = ResultTableName
        FROM #CreateResult_ResultTables lr
        WHERE ID = @ResultTableCount;
```

**--Error :-**

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Procedure_name, Line 141 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure to create tables? This seems pretty scary to me and highly likely to be vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: There is an existing stored proc in an application... Inside the while loop it iterates through a list of table names and creates the tables. but I want to create tables using partitioning for couple of the table names..

Comment: `THEN` accepts expressions, not statements, and the result of a `CASE ... END` is itself an expression. `SELECT @SQLStmt = CASE WHEN ... THEN N'' ELSE ... END`.

Comment: @Jeoren Could you help me in re-writing the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because CASE is a *function* in SQL, but you are using it as though it were a statement or a column form.

```
SELECT
     @SQLStmt =
         CASE WHEN  ResultTableName LIKE '%Loss_ByEvent]'
              THEN  N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + ResultTableName + N' (
                    ' + CreateStmt + N'
                    ) ON Loss_ByAnalysis(SliceID)'                    
              WHEN  ResultTableName LIKE '%Loss_ByGeo]'
              THEN  N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + ResultTableName + N' (
                    ' + CreateStmt + N'
                    ) ON Loss_ByAnalysis(SliceID)'                    
              ELSE 
                    N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + ResultTableName + N' (
                    ' + CreateStmt + N'
                    )'
          END
        ,@DBName = DBName
        ,@ResultTableName = ResultTableName
    FROM #CreateResult_ResultTables lr
    WHERE ID = @ResultTableCount;
```

And @SeanLange is correct, this is *very* vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: It worked fine RbarryYoung... Thank you so much... :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this way

```
SELECT
                 CASE WHEN  ResultTableName LIKE '%Loss_ByEvent]'
                      THEN  'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + ResultTableName + N' (
                            ' + CreateStmt + N'
                            ) ON Loss_ByAnalysis(SliceID)'                    
                      WHEN  ResultTableName LIKE '%Loss_ByGeo]'
                      THEN 
                            N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + ResultTableName + N' (
                            ' + CreateStmt + N'
                            ) ON Loss_ByAnalysis(SliceID)'                    
                      ELSE 
                            N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + ResultTableName + N' (
                            ' + CreateStmt + N'
                            )'
                  END AS Sqlstmt
                ,@DBName = DBName
                ,@ResultTableName = ResultTableName
            FROM #CreateResult_ResultTables lr
            WHERE ID = @ResultTableCount;
```